# Starred message image section in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, script-request

I have almost no experience with javascript, widgets and scripts myself, so I'd like to ask someone to make this useful chat addition a reality.

[(Original Meta.SE feature request)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235178/move-onebox-images-to-separate-section-in-starred-message-list)

The idea is to detect starred messages with only image links and move them to a separate section under the text-only starred messages (links to non-images included):

> [image]

Additionally, it would be cool to see the number of stars an image got on hover, and maybe customize thumbnail size and number of rows.

This feature will be useful for all chat rooms that regularly have interesting images posted.

Comment: Why not? Single scripts are probably easier to make than "apps". Also what is considered an app on this site? :D

Comment: Scripts *are* easier, but we haven't had any other requests that I know about. ... An app is basically a program or webpage that runs outside of SE site(s) (but uses SE data, in this context).  A script, in this case, runs in a browser while browsing SE sites.  There can be a lot of overlap between the two classifications too.  PS: instead of "add the new tag", above, I meant "create the new tag".

Comment: Well, maybe it's time to create that tag then. I have another request in mind and if we don't figure out how to do it ourselves, I might post it here and it'll need that tag too. Also what hard could it do to add it now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is now [an extension](https://github.com/MadaraUchiha/star-thumn) that solved this problem. See [this post](https://stackapps.com/questions/6236/chat-starred-images-expander) for info.