# Chat Starred Images Expander (aka StarScript)

Tags: script, chat, images

### The Thing

This handy little userscript will turn images starred in chat into little thumbnails under the star list.

[image: Example]

### Current features:

- Oneboxed images in chat will become thumbnails.
- Add or remove stars normally. The star button appears on hover.
- Linked images in the form of `[text](image link)` (assuming nothing else on the message) will become thumbnails with `text` being a `title` on the image.
- Images from `googledrive.com` will be properly thumbnailed with the `_thumb` suffix. Link will lead to full size image. *(This is [a thing](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1161/chat-has-pictures-and-they-are-big) specific to our chat room.)*

Here's a little demo gif of starring an image and showing description text on hover:

[image]

### Planned features:

- Proper thumbnailing for imgur images (use the `s` or `m` suffix to save bandwidth)
- Accepting suggestions in answers below.

### Install

You can find the repository that holds the code **[can be found here](https://github.com/MadaraUchiha/star-thumn)**. To install, you must be able to run user scripts. Chrome does this by default (or with Tampermonkey) and Firefox does this with Greasemonkey.

#### *[CLICK HERE TO INSTALL](https://github.com/MadaraUchiha/star-thumn/raw/master/expando.user.js)*

### Extra

Please note that this is still under development, and not all features are guaranteed to work properly.

If you have features, suggestions, bugs, ideas, rants, chickens, praise to the almighty Madara-sama, or anything else you'd like to say, feel free to post an answer below, or open a ticket **[here](https://github.com/MadaraUchiha/star-thumn/issues)**.